# Given a server on Node. js, How do I listen to the calls sent to the server from WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

When I run the server, I wanted to be able to listen to the messages coming in to the server. However, the program/server is only set up to receive the calls without any notice 
server.js

```
var express = require("express"),
program = require("program"),

app = express.createServer();
app.use(express["static"](__dirname + "/../"));
app.listen(5000);
//app.server to clients

program.init({
    oscPort: xxxx,
    oscHost: "xxx.xxx.xxx"
    socketPort: app
});
```

Comment: This is only the server-side JS, do you have you have the client-side JS files too? You also need to install `socket.io` to listen to the socket.

Comment: Yes, but they are bundled into libraries. What I wanted to do was when the server received it, it would wait 5 seconds and then send it as a client back to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add socket server because HTTP and Socket it's different protocols. There is a bunch of WebSocket servers like ws, socket.io so you could pick the one which is most suitable in your case. Here is an [example](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) how to use Socket.io with Express.

Comment: doesn't say anything about init

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by "init", could you explain, please?

Comment: In the format here it uses init() and then when i do program.on, it says program does not have function program.on(...)

Comment: Hmm, the only [program](https://www.npmjs.com/package/program) package that I found doesn't expose even "init" function, could you provide link to a source code of package that you're using?

Comment: Currently, trying to " listen to the messages" coming from this.websocket.onmessage and then send them backout in the same format, but there is not send function

Comment: `on` events is exposed only for the client doesn't seem like the server cannot access to events so you should manually listen and send them from client.

Comment: Yes, can you help me figure out to do that, the client is actually not programmed, and wondering how to program one.

Comment: Will I have to run Node.js twice, or build a function that sends it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115278/discussion-between-konstantin-azizov-and-arrowinfedex).